# SSL context invalid error while using getHttp processor in Nifi

Tags: ssl, curl, https, apache-nifi

When I use curl for an https URL then I am getting a successful response.
[image]  But When I try to hit the same URL using getHttp processor of Nifi then it is throwing ssl context invalid error[image]. So just wanted to understand why and how can I fix the Nifi error. My processor config are [image]

Comment: did you tried to set the parameter `SSL Context Service` ?

Comment: Hi @daggett , that is what I wanted to understand, like why is it required to set SSL context while using Nifi processor but the same was not required while using Curl. And if Curl is using some SSL context then how can I reuse it in Nifi.

Comment: seems, the only way is to use ssl context with parameters: truststore file: `PATH_TO_JAVA/jre/lib/security/cacerts`, truststore pass: `changeit`, truststore type: `JKS`

Answer (score 2):

The URL you are using is HTTPS ,so You must create SSLContextService And pass details shown in this image

[image]